# Shape Android Studio no se aplica

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Buenas tardes compañeros, les agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar, tengo un problema con android studio y es que no me toma los cambios que le aplico al Shape, lo he guardado en los "drawable" pero cuando lo invoco en el botón no me toma los cambios. He visto cantidad de tutoriales y al parecer lo tengo bien, pero no se que me hace falta para que me funcione.

En el **drawable** tengo el siguiente código xml con el nombre buttonshape1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="25dp"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="500dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#01B875"
        />
</shape>
```

lo cual me da la siguiente apariencia que es la que quiero,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando lo aplico a mi boton, usando `android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"` no me da la apariencia del Shape. Tengo este código para el boton.

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/angry_btn"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
```

Al mirar el diseño, sigue estando con los estilos predeterminados de android.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si me pueden echar una mano por favor. Gracias desde yá por sus comentarios.

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Muestro a continuación, un capture completo de mi pantalla en Android Studio, al tomar la respuesta de la primera persona que respondió Franqo, me toma los cambios que quiero hacerle pero mi aplicación al ejecutarla en el movil se ve tal cual con los botones morados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen al poner la opcion Design.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Pues probablemente sea porque en tu `Theme` está asignado el de tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente, cambia el tema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego cambias el color del texto del botón:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Lo que sucede es que en tu `Manifest.xml` tienes la siguiente línea:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Ayudas" //aquí el Theme.Ayudas es porque mi proyecto se llama Ayudas, por lo que en tu `Manfest` saldrá con otro nombre
```

Lo que hace que tu diseño se vea en tu móvil así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que debes hacer es cambiarlo por un tema que te convenga, en mi caso lo cambié por este:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Y se ve como quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos @FranqoBalsamo gracias por la respuesta mas sin embargo al hacer eso que me dices, en el diseño se ve que si toma la apariencia que le quiero dar a los botones, mas sin embargo al ejecutar la aplicacion en el movil fisico, igual no toma los cambios, voy a actualizar la respuesta y mostrar un capture de la pantalla como la tengo.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, espero que te sirva @JonathanArias

Comment: Saludos @FranqoBalsamo, en definitiva no me funcionó con este proyecto lo eliminaré y crearé uno nuevo ya que identifiqué que al crear uno nuevo el efecto del shape si lo toma sin problema, por lo que pude conocer que mi android se encuentra funcionando de manera correcta. agradezco de antemano tu tiempo en ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

No cambia su apariencia a pesar de que colocamos cualquier propiedad de colores y a pesar que se crean y se asignen Drawable

**Solución en...**

https://programersolution77.blogspot.com/2022/02/solucion-problemas-con-el-color-de.html

Comment: Escribe un breve resumen del contenido del enlace que proporcionas: ten en cuenta que tal contenido puede que ya no esté disponible más adelante, volviendo a esta respuesta como inválida. La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Tu shape debe funcionar sin problema, lo que noto es que **tienes una imagen definida desde el lado izquierdo** con :

```
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
```

**Esta imagen puede sobreescribir el estilo definido en el shape para tu botón**, te sugiero eliminarla :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/angry_btn"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape1"

                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
```

para que se pueda mostrar correctamente el estilo de botón que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos @jorgesys quizás ese sea el problema, porque cree un nuevo proyecto y el shape funciona, pero en este caso quiero ponerle un icono al botón, es por eso la imagen que tengo ahí. Siguiendo tu sugerencia como podré ponerle en este caso el icono de Facebook al botón?... Al llegar a casa pruebo tu solución.

Comment: Saludos @Jorgesys he probado tu respuesta y no, parece que en definitiva debe haber un conflicto con el proyecto como tal que no logro saber cual es, sin embargo, al crear un  nuevo proyecto el Shape funciona, lo que quiere decir que mi android está funcionando. Agradezco de igual forma tu apoyo.

Comment: Si sobre pones una imagen a el shape que asignas al botón, no se verá el botón redondeado.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"
```

la cuestión es que por defecto esta usando el tema de la aplicación. que se encuentra en el archivo "theme", el cual tiene un color primario y otro secundario los cuales serán los colores predominantes en la aplicación los botones inicialmente siguen ese patrón de colores.

cambiando el tema en el archivo "manifest" entonces los botones ahora si seguirán el patrón de colores que uno declaro en el shape.

Comment: Esta respuesta sólo le sirve al OP y a nadie más. No enseña, no educa, no explica.

Comment: Podrias explicar porque esto es la solucion??? si no, es solo codigo y no se entiende porque sirve.